# Prevent complilation using a transitive dependency

Tags: maven

If I have a Maven project that depends on A and that depends on B, I can use  classes from the transitive B in my own code.  This is a bad idea, and I should declare my dependency on B explicitly in my POM.

However, is there any way to enforce this at compile time? i.e. cause a build error if I have used classes from B without explicitly declaring a dependency on it?

NOTE: From what I can tell, this is *not* what the `banTransitiveDependencies` enforcer rule does.  That seems to ban any dependencies with transitive dependencies (which is most dependencies!)

Comment: `maven-dependency-plugin` should help: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html